# add a delay to the focusout jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I delay $('#header_user_list').html(''); this line from executing by a second?

application.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#user_header_search_form input").focusout(function() {
    $('#header_user_list').html('');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a 1 second timeout

```
$(function() {
 $("#user_header_search_form input").focusout(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){$('#header_user_list').html('');},1000);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do by javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#header_user_list').html('')}, 1000);
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#user_header_search_form input").focusout(function() {
    $('#header_user_list').html('');
  }).delay(1000);
});
```